# Is ionic devapp for android discontinued by Ionic Team?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Recently I visited https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp. There they have mentioned devapp for devlopment purpose. But when click on playstore link, its saying not found.

Answer (score 0):

strange.. you can download it from here
https://apkpure.com/it/ionic-devapp/io.ionic.devapp/download?from=details

Comment: Thanks :) but is it trustable source to download apk

Comment: apkpure is one of the trustable website, try to google it.

Comment: Its available now on playstore.